# Does the Hellfire weapon exist in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

Does the Hellfire weapon exist in Borderlands 2?

The gun was a force to be reckoned with in the original.

Here is a link: [http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hellfire_(Borderlands)](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hellfire_%28Borderlands%29)

Comment: That thing was so OP, especially in Lilith's hands.

Comment: @SaintWacko loved that gun. No one whines about Maliwan being weak once they see that baby.

Comment: @BenBrocka - Haha, yep! That and, to a slightly lesser extent, the Volcano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, apparently it's a drop from Scorch as there's a Hellfire farming video that instructs you to kill Scorch.

From the stats in the video it has an 18.8% ignore chance with *brutal* Damage over time damage and solid damage for an SMG of that level (though less than a non-elemental of the same level, the fire damage more than makes up for that). Keep in mind that status effect chance is about double normal SMG effect chance, and it's almost 50% with Siren skills and no Badass ranks.

I finally got a hold of one. It's shots explode with fire on every shot, dealing a fair amount of splash damage in a visible radius (half a meter or so). After some testing it does not cause Burn DOT effects any more often than the listed stats indicate, so it's still best in the hands of a Siren with the Flicker skill. Rest assured it is a very powerful SMG, I find it more effective than Moxxie's Bad Touch.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a [Consumate Hellfire SMG](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Maliwan) in Borderlands 2 apparently.  Unfortunately I can't comment on whether it has a 100% proc chance like it's parent weapon in Borderlands.  That article lists it as having a rarity of legendary, though; one presumes it is spectacular.